# What is this plant with narrow stems and serrated leaves growing among my Blueberry bush?

Tags: identification, leaves

We have a blueberry bush that has another plant growing with it. My husband dug it up and carefully untangled the roots.

The blueberry bush is fine and fruiting well.

Can you tell me what this other plant is please?

[image]

Comment: The easy way it is to check nearby tree for similar leaves.  I think it is a Betula (birch), or similar (Populus, etc.). Adding the region where you leave, could help reducing the choices.

Comment: I think you are right, Giacomo.  Sure wish we could have these OPs go through a simple questionnaire as they create their questions.  It is almost impossible to answer a question without asking a bunch more questions  of the OP to get the information we need to answer their question...

Comment: Welcome Pauline Murray! When asking identification questions, we need more information. [Here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) are our guidelines. Can you tell us where you live, and add more pictures, including the whole plant?  Our site is different from some others, so I invite you to visit our [help]. [Ask] is the best place to start. If you need help with how to do anything, just leave us a note and we'll help you!

Answer (score 1):

I could be paranoid but, it looks like wild grapevine to me.If it is, get rid of it quick. You mentioned untangling the roots, that's how it spreads also.Not to mention the tendrils it sends out and wraps around everything and strangling everything it latches on to.Iv'e been battling it for 4 yrs. now. Have to kill the roots. good luck.